# Is there an easy way to access a desktop icon without minimizing all windows?

Tags: windows-7

Is there an easy way to access a desktop icon without minimizing all windows? For example, if I can access the icons from within the start menu, it'd be really helpful. Minimizing all windows does the job, but disrupts my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If your icons change frequently:

- One option is to just open [Windows Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_win_explorer.mspx?mfr=true) (the file browser) and navigate to your `Desktop` there.  You could toggle the one window open and closed as you need.

If your icons aren't going to change all that often:

- Another would be to put all the important shortcuts in your `start menu`.  Just right click the important ones and `Pin To Start`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Desktop toolbar: right click on the Taskbar, go to Toolbars, click Desktop.

[7stacks](http://alastria.com/software/7stacks/) is a great app for this kind of thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pin the shortcut icons to the task bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy access to a few specific shortcuts on your desktop (or anywhere else), you can assign them hotkeys:

[image: Screenshot of Calculator shortcut on desktop with hotkey field highlighted]